# CreateDialogParam never calls WM_INITDIALOG

Tags: windows, dialog

I have a dialog defined in the .rc file as:

```
IDD_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION DIALOGEX 0, 0, 214, 138
STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_SETFOREGROUND | DS_3DLOOK | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_VISIBLE | WS_CAPTION
CAPTION "Dialog"
FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1
BEGIN
    DEFPUSHBUTTON   "Validate",ID_BTN_VALIDATE,102,117,50,14
    PUSHBUTTON      "Exit",ID_BTN_EXIT,157,117,50,14
    LTEXT           "Username",IDC_STATIC,7,9,45,8
    CONTROL         "<a>SysLink</a>",IDC_SYSLINK,"SysLink",WS_TABSTOP,7,99,60,14
    LTEXT           "Password",IDC_STATIC,7,25,45,8
    LTEXT           "messages",IDC_MESSAGE,7,39,197,55
    EDITTEXT        IDC_USERNAME,44,7,140,14,ES_AUTOHSCROLL
    EDITTEXT        IDC_PASSWORD,44,22,140,14,ES_PASSWORD | ES_AUTOHSCROLL
END
```

and the ID is "IDD_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION". CreateDialogParam is called as:

```
HWND hDlgWnd = CreateDialogParamW(GetModuleHandle(NULL),L"IDD_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION", (DLGPROC)dialogProc, (LPARAM)this);
```

but it returns a null HWND and **NO** error code (GetLastError() == 0).

There are several messages sent to my dialogProc function, but **never** WM_INITDIALOG (the messages are WM_SETFONT, 0x0090 (??), WM_DESTROY and WM_NCDESTROY)

OS is Vista 32 bit (no SP).

Any ideas ??

Edited: Ok, the culprit was the SysLink control. Without it I get the WM_INITDIALOG message, and the dialog comes up fine.

But, having the need for a SysLink control I:
1. Link the executable with the comctl32.lib
2. Call InitCommonControlsEx with ICC_LINK_CLASS

However, InitCommonControlsEx fails i.e. returns FALSE, so the question now is how to get the SysLink control to show... :)

Comment: What are you doing with unhandled messages in dialogProc?

Comment: @Will: Just return FALSE

Answer (score 4):

All that you need is

```
#if defined _M_IX86
  #pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='x86' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#elif defined _M_X64
  #pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='amd64' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#else
  #pragma comment(linker, "/manifestdependency:\"type='win32' name='Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' version='6.0.0.0' processorArchitecture='*' publicKeyToken='6595b64144ccf1df' language='*'\"")
#endif
```

in your stdafx.h file.
Or just add manifest with dependency of 'Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls' to the your project.

Answer (score 0):

Change:

```
HWND hDlgWnd = CreateDialogParamW(GetModuleHandle(NULL),L"IDD_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION", (DLGPROC)dialogProc, (LPARAM)this);
```

To:

```
HWND hDlgWnd = CreateDialogParam(GetModuleHandle(NULL), MAKEINTRESOURCE(IDD_DIALOG_AUTHENTICATION), (DLGPROC)dialogProc, (LPARAM)this);
```

Comment: Nope, cannot do that. I'm doing a crossplatform dialog handler, and I need to be able to reference the dialog by name. I have the answer, will soon post it.